# I try to write the java script code like oops how to extend the DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype

In my code like ,

```
    function ElementBase(name) {
         this.tagName = typeof name != "" ? name : 'div';
         this.createElem();
     }

     ElementBase.prototype = {
            createElem: function() {
                this.elem = document.createElement(this.tagName);
            },
            getIndex: function() {
                var nodes = this.elem.parentNode.childNodes,
                    node;
                var i = count = 0;
                while ((node = nodes.item(i++)) && node != this.elem)
                    if (node.nodeType == 1) count++;
                return (count);
            }
};
```

I try to create the DOM element tag is "div".

```
function Div() {

    this.tagName = 'div'
    ElementBase.call(this, this.tagName);
}

Div.prototype = Object.create(ElementBase.prototype);
```

My Question is,

1) How to access the getIndex function from the html document after inserting the created objects?
example:

```
var div = new Div();    
div.id = "d1"
document.body.appendChild(div.elem);
// After div.getIndex() working
```

Then some situation i need the index value of that div (id="d1") element from document.

```
var d= document.getElementById("d1");
d.getIndex()   //not working
```

What mistakes i did it in above code?

thanks advance..

Comment: Take a look into: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements

Comment: It looks like java based structure and syntax. Its may be useful for my code syntax wise only. I give an one example that it is in prototypical method. How do I achieve prototypical inheritance? Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @RobertJ.Hovey No, that's Javascript. It's just using some features of the language you may not be familiar with.

Comment: @duskwuff Ya correct I am the beginner of writing javascript. I want to write a plugin jquery based. So I use to write js prototype based syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you do `document.body.appendChild(div.elem)` you just do `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))` nothing more. 
And when you do `var d= document.getElementById("d1");` `d` is just an object return from the DOM that has nothing to do with your var `div`

what you can do is:

```
Div.prototype.getIndex.call(d);
```

But that doesn't actually extend your object. Actually extending a DOM object is a bad practice (check this http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at your code.

`div` is an instance of `Div` and it has a property `.elem` that holds the actual DOM element.

So when you do `div.id = "d1"`, you are not setting the id of the DOM element.

```
var div = new Div();
div.id = 'd1';      // <div></div>
div.elem.id = 'd1'; // <div id="d1"></div>
```

---

But there's one more problem: when you do `d= document.getElementById("d1")`, what you get is a DOM element, not an instance of `Div()`.

Since `.getIndex()` is defined on `.prototype` of `Div()`, plain old DOM elements don't have access to it.

How you solve this situation depends on what exactly you need to accomplish with your code.

---

**Edit 1**: In response to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554449/i-try-to-write-the-java-script-code-like-oops-how-to-extend-the-dom-elements/42757252?noredirect=1#comment72771034_42757252):

`document.getElementById()` returns an instance of `HTMLDivElement`, which is fundamentally different from an instance of `Div`.

One solution is to use a setter method:

```
function Div() {
    // ...
}
Div.prototype.setId = function setId(id) {
    this.elem.id = id;
}

var div = new Div();
div.setId('d1'); // same as doing div.elem.id = 'd1';
```

another solution is to use id in the constructor function itself:

```
function Div(id) {
    // ...

    this.elem.id = id; // or you can use "this.setId(id)"
    /*
        if "id" is provided, 
        it will take that value,

        else it is set to "undefined",
        which is the same as not being set
    */
}
Div.prototype.setId = function setId(id) {
    this.elem.id = id;
}

var div = new Div('d1'); // same as doing div.elem.id = 'd1';
div.setId('d2'); // same as doing div.elem.id = 'd2';
```

Comment: In my code has errors . I mention that in my above question. I try to set the DOM element id in the way you mentioned(div.id). I don't want to write like this way div.elem.id. I try to define the object that able to changes the property